# How to control MapControl pushpin text from click events

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to use some pushpins I've added to my MapControl to be manipulated as desired but for some reason, my pushpin marker is not found despite being declared in XAML.

In this instance, what would be the correct way to find the relevant items to achieve the following?:

- Show text above pushpin (if collapsed) when the pushpin is clicked
- Hide text label above pushpin (if visible) when the pushpin is clicked, or, if any other area of the MapControl is clicked (both outside the pushpin and text label)
- Ensure only 1 pushpin text label is visible at anytime (to prevent overlapping labels)

**XAML**

```
<maps:MapControl x:Name="myMap" Loaded="MyMap_Loaded" Grid.Row="2">
    <maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapItems">
        <maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Button x:Name="mapItemBalloonButton" Click="mapItemBalloonButton_Click" Background="Transparent">
                        <Border x:Name="PinText" 
                                Visibility="Collapsed"
                                Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                                Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                Padding="10">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" 
                                       Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Button>
                    <Button x:Name="mapItemIconButton" Click="mapItemIconButton_Click" Background="Transparent">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image x:Name="PinImage"
                               Source="{Binding ImageSourceUri}"
                               maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding NormalizedAnchorPoint}"
                               maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}">
                                <Image.Transitions>
                                    <TransitionCollection>
                                        <EntranceThemeTransition/>
                                    </TransitionCollection>
                                </Image.Transitions>
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </maps:MapItemsControl>
</maps:MapControl>
```

**C#**

```
public class PointOfInterest
{
    public string PinName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public Geopoint Location { get; set; }
    public Uri ImageSourceUri { get; set; }
    public Point NormalizedAnchorPoint { get; set; }
}

public sealed partial class Scenario3 : Page
{
    public Scenario3()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myMap.Center = MainPage.SeattleGeopoint;
        myMap.ZoomLevel = 16;
    }

    private void addXamlChildrenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BasicGeoposition center = myMap.Center.Position;
        var pinUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/MapPin.png");
        MapItems.ItemsSource = new List<PointOfInterest>()
        {
            new PointOfInterest()
            {
                PinName = "Pin1",
                DisplayName = "Place One",
                ImageSourceUri = pinUri,
                NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1),
                Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                {
                    Latitude = center.Latitude + 0.001,
                    Longitude = center.Longitude - 0.001
                })
            },
            new PointOfInterest()
            {
                PinName = "Pin2",
                DisplayName = "Place Two",
                ImageSourceUri = pinUri,
                NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1),
                Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                {
                    Latitude = center.Latitude + 0.001,
                    Longitude = center.Longitude + 0.001
                })
            },
            new PointOfInterest()
            {
                PinName = "Pin3",
                DisplayName = "Place Three",
                ImageSourceUri = pinUri,
                NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1),
                Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                {
                    Latitude = center.Latitude - 0.001,
                    Longitude = center.Longitude - 0.001
                })
            },
            new PointOfInterest()
            {
                PinName = "Pin4",
                DisplayName = "Place Four",
                ImageSourceUri = pinUri,
                NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1),
                Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
                {
                    Latitude = center.Latitude - 0.001,
                    Longitude = center.Longitude + 0.001
                })
            }
        };
    }

    private async void mapItemBalloonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ContentDialog myDialog = new ContentDialog
        {
            Title = "Hello World",
            Content = "Hello World",
            CloseButtonText = "OK"
        };
        ContentDialogResult result = await myDialog.ShowAsync();
    }

    private void mapItemIconButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mapItemBalloonButton.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
        {
            mapItemBalloonButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            mapItemBalloonButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your needs, it is recommended to use Flyout as the pop-up layer. If you put `mapItemBalloonButton` and `mapItemButton` in the `StackPanel`, it will cause element dislocation.

```xml
<Button x:Name="mapItemButton" Click="mapItemButton_Click" Background="Transparent"
        >
    <Button.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
            <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                </Style>
            </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
            <Button x:Name="mapItemBalloonButton" Click="mapItemBalloonButton_Click" Background="Transparent">
                <Border x:Name="PinText" 
                        Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                        Margin="0,0,0,5"
                        Padding="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"/>
                </Border>
            </Button>
        </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>

    <!-- Content here -->

</Button>
```

Flyout's own features can meet the three requirements you put forward.

Comment: Great. Is there a way to prevent the Flyout from being clickable for certain items (e.g. for Pin1 and Pin3, I do not want the flyout to be clickable)?

Comment: Hello, you can set `IsEnabled` of the parent Button corresponding to Pin1 or Pin3 to `False`, so that clicking the button will not trigger Flyout.

Comment: Hello again. Do I need to use data binding for that? e.g. `IsEnabled={Binding BtnEnabled}`

Comment: Yes, this is a relatively simple method. But if you need to dynamically modify it and let the UI respond to the modification of the property, you need to let the PointOfInterest class inherit the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=winrt-19041) interface

Comment: Is there any example code of this around somewhere? I am not sure where within the class file I need to put the code.

Comment: Hello, there are complete code examples and calling methods in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=winrt-19041#examples). What you have to do is to make your data class (`PointerOfInterest`) implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and implement the events defined by the interface internally. Modify the define of the `BtnEnabled` property to notify the UI.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of code required. Would a simple if statement work for this? e.g. if (clickedTab == tab1) {myFlyout.IsClickable = false}

Comment: Hello, Is the `IsClickable` a self-defined property? If it is, then only modifying the property in the code-behind will not notify the UI to also change (if you use binding)